# Why does my Timer come back null when I have inherited it?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have the interface:

```
 public interface IProcess
    {
        void Step_One();
        void Step_Two();
        Timer ProcessTimer{get; set;}
    }
```

the base class..

```
 public class ProcessBase
    {
        protected Timer processTimer;
        public Timer ProcessTimer{get{ return processTimer;}set{processTimer=value;}}



        //sets up all the common objects
        public ProcessBase() 
        {


        }

        //This constructor will call the default constructor ^
        protected ProcessBase(long intervalArg) : this()
        {
            processTimer = new Timer(intervalArg);
            processTimer.Enabled = true;

        }

    }
```

the concrete class

```
public class ReportedContentProcess : ProcessBase, IProcess
{

    public ReportedContentProcess(): base(5000)
    {

    }

    public void Step_One()
    {
    }

    public void Step_Two()
    {
    }
}
```

but when I try and get it out in a factory...

```
public static class ProcessFactory
    {

        public static List<IProcess> GetProcessors()
        {

            ReportedContentProcess.ReportedContentProcess reportedContentProcess = new ReportedContentProcess.ReportedContentProcess();

            List<IProcess> retProcesses = new List<IProcess>();
            retProcesses.Add(reportedContentProcess);
            return retProcesses;

        }   
    }
```

and then attach a handler to the timer...

```
processorsForService = ProcessFactory.GetProcessors();


                foreach(IProcess p in processorsForService)
                {
                    p.ProcessTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(IProcess_Timer_Elapsed);
                }
```

I get a run-time error saying that the p.ProcessTimer is null. Why is this? I have inherited and instantiated in the base class cant understand why its null. Ive even included it in the interface...

Comment: Why do you have 2 constructors? Why don't have one that initialize `Timer` and all other objects?

Comment: No explanation from the snippets.  Use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on both constructors.

Comment: i copied the code and it works well, what .net version/ide are you using?

Comment: it should work. i think you're executing the last codeblock before the timer is made, have you tried stepping through your program?

Comment: >  ReportedContentProcess.ReportedContentProcess < looks odd - double-check by single-stepping that you're actually calling the right class

Comment: The code above should work like a charm.  I guess you miss some part in you "clean and copy to stackoverflow" process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're initializing `Timer` in second constructor only. What if the default one is called (i.e. the constructor that is without params)?

Comment: The constructor that's being called is the other one.  That's not the issue here though you made a point about how theses class are designed.

Comment: @VdesmedT His code is not very clear. This constructor maybe called causing `NullReferenceException` later.